# Автоматическая регулировка скорости вращения кулера Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

Имеется ноутбук ASUS с Ubuntu 16.04.2 на борту, и ситуация такая - сейчас вот например температура процессора 51 градус, а кулер крутится на все свои 4100 оборотов, создавая дискомфорт моей нежной программистской психике и забиваясь всевозможной пылью. Задача - настроить автоматическую регулировку скорости вращения кулера "как под виндой". Почему-то 90% нагугленных мною статей датируются бородатыми годами, а оставшиеся 10% тыкают меня носом в проприетарные драйвера видеокарт nVidia (они-то стоят, но как они мне помогут с кулером на проце? а никак, от слова "совсем"). Может, есть у кого годный мануал? Схемка, чертёж, аль ссылка какая.

ноут ASUS, проц i5, если ещё нужны какие-то данные, допишу, не проблема

Comment: TLP или laptop-mode-tools уже пробовали ставить?

Comment: Клссический lm-sensors с pwmconfig не подошёл?